# Unity3D Input.GetKeyDown and OnTriggerEnter problem

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, triggers

This is my first time submitting a problem here. It’s in first person. The problem I’m having, is that when the player enters the box collider and presses E the text with E show up but then when I click E it sometimes switch the lights and sometimes not. I have one scripts, LightOnOff, which is attached to the component with the light and with the box collider(trigger). I can’t seem to figure out a solution to this problem and any help would be much appreciated.
Here is the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LightOnOff : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject intText;
    Light myLight;

    public KeyCode interactionKey = KeyCode.E;
    

    void Start()
    {
        myLight = GetComponent<Light>();
    }    

    void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.CompareTag("MainCamera"))
        {
            intText.SetActive(true);

            if(Input.GetKeyDown(interactionKey))
            {
                myLight.enabled = !myLight.enabled;
            }            
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.CompareTag("MainCamera"))
        {
            intText.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Things like `Input.GetKeyDown()` behave weirdly inside of OnTrigger Callbacks. Try using `Input.GetKeyDown()` in `Update()` like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LightOnOff : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject intText;
    Light myLight;

    public KeyCode interactionKey = KeyCode.E;

    private bool isCameraInTrigger;
    

    void Start()
    {
        myLight = GetComponent<Light>();
    }    

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.CompareTag("MainCamera"))
        {
            intText.SetActive(true);

            isCameraInTrigger = true;        
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.CompareTag("MainCamera"))
        {
            intText.SetActive(false);
            isCameraInTrigger = false;        
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(interactionKey))
        {
            myLight.enabled = !myLight.enabled;
        }  

    }
}
```